# In TypeScript, how do you you type specific keys to object literal

Tags: typescript

So I have this data structure

```
export interface StoreData {
    msdb: {[tableName: string]: List<StoreModel>};
}
```

but I would like to only allow (and get IntelliSence) on specific string values for my tableName.
So I tried something like the following but it didn't work:

```
var tableNames:'table_campaigns' | 'table_resources'
export interface StoreData {
    msdb: {[tableName]: List<StoreModel>};
}
```

also tried with no luck

```
interface IMyTables {
    'table_campaigns: string
    'table_resources: string;
}

type MyTables = keyof IMyTables;

export interface StoreData {
    participants: { [key: number]: any };
    threads: { [key: number]: any };
    messages: { [key: number]: any };
    msdb: {MyTables: List<StoreModel>};
}
```

also tried

```
type allMyTables = 'table_campaigns' | 'table_resources'

export interface StoreData {
    msdb: {[tableName: allMyTables]: List<StoreModel>};
}




Thanks for reading,

Sean
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but why don't you add the explicit properties instead of indexing?  `msdb: {[tableName: string]: List<StoreModel>, table_campaigns: List<StoreModel>, table_resources: List<StoreModel>};`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Jeff, that did it:

```
export interface StoreData {
    participants: { [key: number]: any };
    threads: { [key: number]: any };
    messages: { [key: number]: any };
    msdb: {
        'table_campaigns': List<StoreModel>;
        'table_resources': List<StoreModel>;
    };
}
```